# Why do the functions in std::io::Read take a buffer?

Tags: file, io, rust

Why do the methods in [`std::io::Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html), namely `read_to_end`, `read_to_string`, and `read_exact` take a buffer rather than returning the result? The current return value is a `Result<usize>` (or `Result<()>`), but could that not be made into a tuple instead, also containing the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 517](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0517-io-os-reform.md#read) discusses these functions and describes two reasons for why the functions take buffers over returning values:

> - Performance. When it is known that reading will involve some large number of bytes, the buffer can be preallocated in advance.
> - "Atomicity" concerns. For read_to_end, it's possible to use this API to retain data collected so far even when a read fails in the middle. For read_to_string, this is not the case, because UTF-8 validity cannot be ensured in such cases; but if intermediate results are wanted, one can use read_to_end and convert to a String only at the end.

For the first point, a string can be pre-allocated using the associated function [`String::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.with_capacity). A very similar function exists for vectors: [`Vec::with_capacity`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity).